# Bootstrap how to change margins automatically with screen width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

On fullscreen I have the margins set to have the container fit entirely within the page, without the margin: 200px in margins in .gallery the container would be to big to fit on the page without having to scroll to see it all

The isssue Im running into is when the screen width shrinks the margins stay the same and push the container out of existence

I am trying to use @media only screen max-width to change it alongside the screen width changes. But at dimensions 367x667 (iphone SE dimensions) the container is completely pushed in. How can I change this so that the container still appears at those dimensions?

```css
  @media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    .gallery{
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 40px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
  }

.gallery-dog-img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  }

.gallery{
  padding: 40px 40px;
  margin: 200px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<section class="gallery bg-primary">
  <div class="container-sm dog-gallery-container">
    <div class="row align-items-center g-0 dog-images-row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3">
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class= "gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from a lack of defined `widths` on your elements. Add `w-100` on your `section` and move `gallery` and `bg-primary` to the parent container div.

Then change `min` to `max-width` on your media query. `max-width` specify styles for all sizes **below** the specified width.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .gallery {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 40px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
}

.gallery-dog-img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
}

.gallery {
  padding: 40px 40px;
  margin: 200px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<section class="w-100">
  <div class="container-sm dog-gallery-container bg-primary gallery">
    <div class="row align-items-center g-0 dog-images-row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3">
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class="gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class="gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class="gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class="gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class="gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class="gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center dog-cell">
        <img class="gallery-dog-img rounded-3" src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190728/1500x900" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: When I do this, the entire container aligns to the right, when I try to use d-flex justify-content-center on the section, it goes back to the way it used to be before the changes. Do you why this might be?

Comment: @TheUltraempoleon can you show the container aligning to the right? It's not aligning to the right in the snippet. Also, when I add those specified styles on the `section` I do not see stuff changing to the way it was... Please elaborate a bit and share examples.

Comment: I just added !important to the margin changes in @media and d-flex justify-content-center to the section and seemed to have done the trick ty

Comment: @TheUltraempoleon Glad, you were able to find a solution.